# How to convert tags <img> in markdown file by markdownPDF?

Tags: html, css, markdown, pandoc

I use MarkDownPDF for convert MarkDown file to PDF file, but it's not working good. It's can't convert tag  from this code:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'avatar information'">
  <div style="grid-area: avatar;">
    <img src="avatar.JPG" alt="Alt text" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>

  <div style="grid-area: information; text-align: center;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 45px; font-weight: bolder;">NGUYEN VAN HAI</h1>
    <h2 style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bolder">INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY</h2>
    <h3  style="font-size: 20px;">INTERN NODEJS</h3>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I try convert by many other ways like: pandoc, convertonline,... But those ways is encountered the same problem.
Thanks you for read my problem.
Can you helps me?

Comment: this way still have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. I'd recommend to use pandoc with a different pdf engine, for example [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org):

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=weasyprint --output=my.pdf ...
```

The reason why this would work is that pandoc passes raw HTML on unchanged when using an HTML-based PDF-converter, but discards it when going via LaTeX.